# Convert data rows in column wise insql

Tags: mysql

I have multiple number of rows. I want to change into column wise.

My data

```
PondCrop    DOC ABW TargetABW
01PA01-18   7   0   0.21
01PA01-18   15  0.59    0.77
01PA01-18   22  1.24    1.5
01PA01-18   28  0.92    2.6
01PA01-18   35  1.82    3.7
01PA01-18   42  2.6 4.8
01PA01-18   49  3.62    5.9
01PA01-18   56  4.64    7
01PA01-18   63  5.54    8.1
01PA01-18   66  6.24    8.1
01PA01-18   73  7.25    9.2
01PA02-18   7   0   0.21
01PA02-18   15  0.59    0.77
01PA02-18   22  1.24    1.5
01PA02-18   28  0.87    2.6
01PA02-18   35  1.8 3.7
01PA02-18   42  2.4 4.8
01PA02-18   49  3.51    5.9
01PA02-18   56  4.6 7
01PA02-18   63  5.51    8.1
01PA02-18   66  6.53    8.1
01PA02-18   73  7.42    9.2
01PA03-18   14  0.53    0.77
01PA03-18   21  1.14    1.5
01PA03-18   27  0.91    1.5
01PA03-18   34  1.67    2.6
01PA03-18   41  2.2 3.7
01PA03-18   48  3.24    4.8
01PA03-18   55  4.31    5.9
01PA03-18   62  4.94    7
01PA03-18   65  5.44    8.1
01PA03-18   72  6.41    9.2
01PA04-18   14  0.53    0.77
01PA04-18   21  1.14    1.5
01PA04-18   27  0.9 1.5
01PA04-18   34  1.52    2.6
01PA04-18   41  1.9 3.7
01PA04-18   48  2.6 4.8
01PA04-18   55  3.52    5.9
01PA04-18   62  4.21    7
01PA04-18   65  4.82    8.1
01PA04-18   72  5.87    9.2
01PA05-18   14  0.53    0.77
01PA05-18   21  1.14    1.5
01PA05-18   27  0.92    1.5
01PA05-18   34  1.49    2.6
01PA05-18   41  1.91    3.7
01PA05-18   48  2.64    4.8
01PA05-18   55  3.69    5.9
01PA05-18   62  4.19    7
01PA05-18   65  4.72    8.1
01PA05-18   72  5.74    9.2
01PA06-18   13  0.48    0.21
01PA06-18   20  1.04    0.77
01PA06-18   26  0.74    1.5
01PA06-18   33  1.25    2.6
01PA06-18   40  1.82    3.7
01PA06-18   47  3.12    4.8
01PA06-18   54  4.4 5.9
01PA06-18   61  5.44    7
01PA06-18   64  6.46    8.1
01PA06-18   71  7.3 9.2
01PA07-18   13  0.48    0.21
01PA07-18   20  1.04    0.77
01PA07-18   26  0.72    1.5
01PA07-18   33  1.32    2.6
01PA07-18   40  1.84    3.7
01PA07-18   47  3.05    4.8
01PA07-18   54  4.12    5.9
01PA07-18   61  5.21    7
01PA07-18   64  6   8.1
01PA07-18   71  6.9 9.2
01PA08-18   13  0.48    0.21
01PA08-18   20  1.04    0.77
01PA08-18   26  0.7 1.5
01PA08-18   33  1.3 2.6
01PA08-18   40  1.8 3.7
01PA08-18   47  3.07    4.8
01PA08-18   54  3.72    5.9
01PA08-18   61  4.52    7
01PA08-18   64  5.11    8.1
01PA08-18   71  5.87    9.2
01PA09-18   13  0.48    0.21
01PA09-18   20  1.04    0.77
01PA09-18   26  0.71    1.5
01PA09-18   33  1.22    2.6
01PA09-18   40  1.85    3.7
01PA09-18   47  2.9 4.8
01PA09-18   54  3.74    5.9
01PA09-18   61  4.4 7
01PA09-18   64  4.92    8.1
01PA09-18   71  5.78    9.2
01PB01-19   8   0   0.21
01PB01-19   15  0   0.77
01PB01-19   23  0.94    1.5
01PB01-19   30  1.85    2.6
01PB01-19   36  2.5 3.7
01PB01-19   43  3.1 4.8
01PB01-19   50  3.74    5.9
01PB01-19   57  5.05    7
01PB01-19   64  6.18    8.1
01PB01-19   71  7.03    9.2
01PB01-19   74  7.87    9.2
01PB01-19   81  8.41    10.3
01PB02-19   8   0   0.21
01PB02-19   15  0   0.77
01PB02-19   23  0.98    1.5
01PB02-19   30  1.82    2.6
01PB02-19   36  2.6 3.7
01PB02-19   43  3.4 4.8
01PB02-19   50  4   5.9
01PB02-19   57  5.5 7
01PB02-19   64  6.72    8.1
01PB02-19   71  7.5 9.2
01PB02-19   74  8.43    9.2
01PB02-19   81  9.6 10.3
01PB03-19   8   0   0.21
01PB03-19   15  0   0.77
01PB03-19   23  0.92    1.5
01PB03-19   30  1.88    2.6
01PB03-19   36  2.51    3.7
01PB03-19   43  3   4.8
01PB03-19   50  3.4 5.9
01PB03-19   57  5.03    7
01PB03-19   64  6.27    8.1
01PB03-19   71  7.32    9.2
01PB03-19   74  8.2 9.2
01PB03-19   81  9.6 10.3
01PB04-19   13  0   0.21
01PB04-19   21  1.14    1.5
01PB04-19   28  0.93    2.6
01PB04-19   34  1.3 2.6
01PB04-19   41  2.1 3.7
01PB04-19   48  2.9 4.8
01PB04-19   55  3.7 5.9
01PB04-19   62  4.49    7
01PB04-19   69  5.3 8.1
01PB04-19   72  6.08    9.2
01PB04-19   79  7.55    10.3
01PB05-19   13  0   0.21
01PB05-19   21  1.14    1.5
01PB05-19   28  0.83    2.6
01PB05-19   34  1.41    2.6
01PB05-19   41  1.9 3.7
01PB05-19   48  2.6 4.8
01PB05-19   55  3.37    5.9
01PB05-19   62  4.32    7
01PB05-19   69  5.03    8.1
01PB05-19   72  5.84    9.2
01PB05-19   79  6.9 10.3
01PB06-19   13  0   0.21
01PB06-19   21  1.14    1.5
01PB06-19   28  0.86    2.6
01PB06-19   34  1.4 2.6
01PB06-19   41  2.2 3.7
01PB06-19   48  2.9 4.8
01PB06-19   55  3.5 5.9
01PB06-19   62  4.61    7
01PB06-19   69  5.3 8.1
01PB06-19   72  6.18    9.2
01PB06-19   79  7.06    10.3
01PB07-19   12  0   0.21
01PB07-19   20  1.04    0.77
01PB07-19   27  0.85    1.5
01PB07-19   33  1.06    2.6
01PB07-19   40  1.96    3.7
01PB07-19   47  2.6 4.8
01PB07-19   54  3.45    5.9
01PB07-19   61  4.23    7
01PB07-19   68  5.04    8.1
01PB07-19   71  5.85    9.2
01PB07-19   78  6.7 10.3
01PB08-19   12  0   0.21
01PB08-19   20  1.04    0.77
01PB08-19   27  0.85    1.5
01PB08-19   33  1.2 2.6
01PB08-19   40  1.9 3.7
01PB08-19   47  2.7 4.8
01PB08-19   54  3.62    5.9
01PB08-19   61  4.49    7
01PB08-19   68  5.13    8.1
01PB08-19   71  6   9.2
01PB08-19   78  6.9 10.3
01PB09-19   12  0   0.21
01PB09-19   20  1.04    0.77
01PB09-19   27  0.78    1.5
01PB09-19   33  1.4 2.6
01PB09-19   40  2   3.7
01PB09-19   47  2.7 4.8
01PB09-19   54  3.86    5.9
01PB09-19   61  5.47    7
01PB09-19   68  6.03    8.1
01PB09-19   71  6.9 9.2
01PB09-19   78  7.5 10.3
01PC01-19   8   0   0.21
01PC01-19   15  0   0.77
01PC01-19   23  1.34    1.5
01PC01-19   30  1.77    2.6
01PC01-19   36  2.1 3.7
01PC01-19   43  3.2 4.8
01PC01-19   50  3.7 5.9
01PC01-19   57  4.6 7
01PC01-19   64  5.5 8.1
01PC01-19   71  6   9.2
01PC01-19   74  7   9.2
01PC01-19   81  7.4 10.3
01PC02-19   7   0   0.21
01PC02-19   14  0   0.77
01PC02-19   22  1.24    1.5
01PC02-19   29  1.56    2.6
01PC02-19   35  2.4 3.7
01PC02-19   42  3.1 4.8
01PC02-19   49  3.5 5.9
01PC02-19   56  4.34    7
01PC02-19   63  5.3 8.1
01PC02-19   70  6.2 9.2
01PC02-19   73  7   9.2
01PC02-19   80  7.85    10.3
01PC03-19   7   0   0.21
01PC03-19   14  0   0.77
01PC03-19   22  1.24    1.5
01PC03-19   29  1.62    2.6
01PC03-19   35  2.2 3.7
01PC03-19   42  2.6 4.8
01PC03-19   49  3.1 5.9
01PC03-19   56  4.1 7
01PC03-19   63  5   8.1
01PC03-19   70  5.9 9.2
01PC03-19   73  6.5 9.2
01PC03-19   80  7.6 10.3
01PC04-20   13  0   0.21
01PC04-20   21  1.14    1.5
01PC04-20   28  0.81    2.6
01PC04-20   34  1.5 2.6
01PC04-20   41  2.2 3.7
01PC04-20   48  2.9 4.8
01PC04-20   55  3.4 5.9
01PC04-20   62  4.5 7
01PC04-20   69  5   8.1
01PC04-20   72  6   9.2
01PC04-20   79  6.9 10.3
01PC05-19   13  0   0.21
01PC05-19   21  1.14    1.5
01PC05-19   28  0.88    2.6
01PC05-19   34  1.22    2.6
01PC05-19   41  2   3.7
01PC05-19   48  2.54    4.8
01PC05-19   55  3.1 5.9
01PC05-19   62  4.2 7
01PC05-19   69  4.6 8.1
01PC05-19   72  5.5 9.2
01PC05-19   79  6.2 10.3
01PC06-19   11  0   0.21
01PC06-19   19  0.94    0.77
01PC06-19   26  0.85    1.5
01PC06-19   32  1.05    2.6
01PC06-19   39  2.3 3.7
01PC06-19   46  2.9 4.8
01PC06-19   53  3.8 5.9
01PC06-19   60  4.3 7
01PC06-19   67  5   8.1
01PC06-19   70  5.8 9.2
01PC06-19   77  6.8 10.3
01PC07-19   11  0   0.21
01PC07-19   19  0.94    0.77
01PC07-19   26  0.79    1.5
01PC07-19   32  1.4 2.6
01PC07-19   39  1.98    3.7
01PC07-19   46  2.7 4.8
01PC07-19   53  3   5.9
01PC07-19   60  3.9 7
01PC07-19   67  5   8.1
01PC07-19   70  5.6 9.2
01PC07-19   77  6.14    10.3
01PC08-19   11  0   0.21
01PC08-19   19  0.94    0.77
01PC08-19   26  0.9 1.5
01PC08-19   32  1.2 2.6
01PC08-19   39  2   3.7
01PC08-19   46  2.5 4.8
01PC08-19   53  3   5.9
01PC08-19   60  4.1 7
01PC08-19   67  4.91    8.1
01PC08-19   70  5.5 9.2
01PC08-19   77  6   10.3
01PC09-20   11  0   0.21
01PC09-20   19  0.94    0.77
01PC09-20   26  0.8 1.5
01PC09-20   32  1.2 2.6
01PC09-20   39  1.95    3.7
01PC09-20   46  2.65    4.8
01PC09-20   53  3   5.9
01PC09-20   60  4.18    7
01PC09-20   67  5   8.1
01PC09-20   70  5.8 9.2
01PC09-20   77  6.4 10.3
01PD01-09   10  0   0.21
01PD01-09   18  0.84    0.77
01PD01-09   25  0.78    1.5
01PD01-09   31  1.02    2.6
01PD01-09   38  1.92    3.7
01PD01-09   45  2.52    4.8
01PD01-09   52  3.4 5.9
01PD01-09   59  4.11    7
01PD01-09   66  5.03    8.1
01PD01-09   69  5.7 8.1
01PD01-09   76  6.7 9.2
01PD02-09   10  0   0.21
01PD02-09   18  0.84    0.77
01PD02-09   25  0.8 1.5
01PD02-09   31  1.03    2.6
01PD02-09   38  1.88    3.7
01PD02-09   45  2.47    4.8
01PD02-09   52  3.33    5.9
01PD02-09   59  4.04    7
01PD02-09   66  4.85    8.1
01PD02-09   69  5.6 8.1
01PD02-09   76  6.45    9.2
01PD03-09   10  0   0.21
01PD03-09   18  0.84    0.77
01PD03-09   25  0.81    1.5
01PD03-09   31  0.99    2.6
01PD03-09   38  1.8 3.7
01PD03-09   45  2.45    4.8
01PD03-09   52  3.14    5.9
01PD03-09   59  4.01    7
01PD03-09   66  4.91    8.1
01PD03-09   69  5.5 8.1
01PD03-09   76  6.5 9.2
01PD04-09   8   0   0.21
01PD04-09   16  0.64    0.77
01PD04-09   23  0.67    1.5
01PD04-09   29  0.96    2.6
01PD04-09   36  1.9 3.7
01PD04-09   43  2.53    4.8
01PD04-09   50  3.26    5.9
01PD04-09   57  4.38    7
01PD04-09   64  5.42    8.1
01PD04-09   67  6.03    8.1
01PD04-09   74  6.6 9.2
01PD05-09   8   0   0.21
01PD05-09   16  0.64    0.77
01PD05-09   23  0.7 1.5
01PD05-09   29  1.02    2.6
01PD05-09   36  2.07    3.7
01PD05-09   43  2.72    4.8
01PD05-09   50  3.6 5.9
01PD05-09   57  4.56    7
01PD05-09   64  5.52    8.1
01PD05-09   67  6.2 8.1
01PD05-09   74  6.9 9.2
01PD08-09   8   0   0.21
01PD08-09   16  0.64    0.77
01PD08-09   23  0.86    1.5
01PD08-09   29  1.34    2.6
01PD08-09   36  2.23    3.7
01PD08-09   43  2.77    4.8
01PD08-09   50  3.79    5.9
01PD08-09   57  4.59    7
01PD08-09   64  5.62    8.1
01PD08-09   67  5.97    8.1
01PD08-09   74  7   9.2
01PD09-09   8   0   0.21
01PD09-09   16  0.64    0.77
01PD09-09   23  0.82    1.5
01PD09-09   29  1.34    2.6
01PD09-09   36  2.35    3.7
01PD09-09   43  2.79    4.8
01PD09-09   50  3.82    5.9
01PD09-09   57  4.64    7
01PD09-09   64  5.65    8.1
01PD09-09   67  6.04    8.1
01PD09-09   74  7.04    9.2
01PD10-10   14  0.53    0.77
01PD10-10   21  1.14    1.5
01PD10-10   27  0.89    1.5
01PD10-10   34  1.69    2.6
01PD10-10   41  2.31    3.7
01PD10-10   48  3.14    4.8
01PD10-10   55  4.2 5.9
01PD10-10   62  5.22    7
01PD10-10   65  5.82    8.1
01PD10-10   72  6.84    9.2
03PA01-17   11  0.37    0.21
03PA01-17   18  0.84    0.77
03PA01-17   24  0.75    1.5
03PA01-17   31  1.65    2.6
03PA01-17   38  2.5 3.7
03PA01-17   45  3.45    4.8
03PA01-17   52  4.1 5.9
03PA01-17   59  4.56    7
03PA01-17   62  4.8 7
03PA01-17   69  5.6 8.1
03PA02-17   11  0.37    0.21
03PA02-17   18  0.84    0.77
03PA02-17   24  0.55    1.5
03PA02-17   31  1.5 2.6
03PA02-17   38  2.3 3.7
03PA02-17   45  3.3 4.8
03PA02-17   52  4.4 5.9
03PA02-17   59  5.06    7
03PA02-17   62  5.5 7
03PA02-17   69  6.4 8.1
03PA03-17   11  0.37    0.21
03PA03-17   18  0.84    0.77
03PA03-17   24  0.65    1.5
03PA03-17   31  1.7 2.6
03PA03-17   38  2.16    3.7
03PA03-17   45  3.1 4.8
03PA03-17   52  4.3 5.9
03PA03-17   59  6.14    7
03PA03-17   62  6.5 7
03PA03-17   69  7.3 8.1
03PA04-16   11  0.37    0.21
03PA04-16   18  0.84    0.77
03PA04-16   24  0.45    1.5
03PA04-16   31  1.4 2.6
03PA04-16   38  2.1 3.7
03PA04-16   45  2.95    4.8
03PA04-16   52  4   5.9
03PA04-16   59  4.23    7
03PA04-16   62  4.7 7
03PA04-16   69  5.6 8.1
03PA05-16   9   0.26    0.21
03PA05-16   16  0.64    0.77
03PA05-16   22  1.34    1.5
03PA05-16   29  1.35    2.6
03PA05-16   36  2.2 3.7
03PA05-16   43  3.15    4.8
03PA05-16   50  3.9 5.9
03PA05-16   57  4.46    7
03PA05-16   60  4.8 7
03PA05-16   67  5.8 8.1
03PA06-16   7   0.19    0.21
03PA06-16   14  0.53    0.77
03PA06-16   20  1.14    0.77
03PA06-16   27  0.65    1.5
03PA06-16   34  1.4 2.6
03PA06-16   41  2.6 3.7
03PA06-16   48  3.7 4.8
03PA06-16   55  4.44    5.9
03PA06-16   58  4.85    7
03PA06-16   65  6   8.1
03PA07-16   8   0.22    0.21
03PA07-16   14  0.59    0.77
03PA07-16   21  0.55    1.5
03PA07-16   28  1.25    2.6
03PA07-16   35  2.4 3.7
03PA07-16   42  3.5 4.8
03PA07-16   49  4.18    5.9
03PA07-16   52  4.55    5.9
03PA07-16   59  5.7 7
03PA08-17   8   0.22    0.21
03PA08-17   14  0.59    0.77
03PA08-17   21  0.68    1.5
03PA08-17   28  1.5 2.6
03PA08-17   35  2.65    3.7
03PA08-17   42  3.9 4.8
03PA08-17   49  5.3 5.9
03PA08-17   52  5.8 5.9
03PA08-17   59  7.6 7
03PB02-16   7   0.19    0.21
03PB02-16   14  0.53    0.77
03PB02-16   20  1.14    0.77
03PB02-16   27  0.7 1.5
03PB02-16   34  1.6 2.6
03PB02-16   41  2.6 3.7
03PB02-16   48  3   4.8
03PB02-16   55  4.22    5.9
03PB02-16   58  4.65    7
03PB02-16   65  5.8 8.1
03PB05-16   13  0.48    0.21
03PB05-16   19  1.04    0.77
03PB05-16   26  0.9 1.5
03PB05-16   33  1.5 2.6
03PB05-16   40  2.5 3.7
03PB05-16   47  3.1 4.8
03PB05-16   54  3.78    5.9
03PB05-16   57  4.45    7
03PB05-16   64  5.6 8.1
03PB06-16   13  0.48    0.21
03PB06-16   19  1.04    0.77
03PB06-16   26  0.9 1.5
03PB06-16   33  1.7 2.6
03PB06-16   40  2.5 3.7
03PB06-16   47  3   4.8
03PB06-16   54  3.47    5.9
03PB06-16   57  4.1 7
03PB06-16   64  5   8.1
03PB07-16   13  0.48    0.21
03PB07-16   19  1.04    0.77
03PB07-16   26  0.7 1.5
03PB07-16   33  1.6 2.6
03PB07-16   40  2.4 3.7
03PB07-16   47  3   4.8
03PB07-16   54  3.5 5.9
03PB07-16   57  4   7
03PB07-16   64  4.8 8.1
03PB08-15   12  0.42    0.21
03PB08-15   18  0.94    0.77
03PB08-15   25  0.9 1.5
03PB08-15   32  1.5 2.6
03PB08-15   39  2.6 3.7
03PB08-15   46  3.1 4.8
03PB08-15   53  5.66    5.9
03PB08-15   56  6.1 7
03PB08-15   63  7   8.1
03PC01-16   7   0.22    0.21
03PC01-16   10  0.37    0.21
03PC01-16   17  0.84    0.77
03PC02-16   12  0.42    0.21
03PC02-16   18  0.94    0.77
03PC02-16   25  1.01    1.5
03PC02-16   32  1.73    2.6
03PC02-16   39  2.59    3.7
03PC02-16   46  3.25    4.8
03PC02-16   53  3.82    5.9
03PC02-16   56  4.15    7
03PC02-16   63  5.33    8.1
03PC03-16   9   0.26    0.21
03PC03-16   15  0.64    0.77
03PC03-16   22  1.01    1.5
03PC03-16   29  1.84    2.6
03PC03-16   36  2.31    3.7
03PC03-16   43  3.32    4.8
03PC03-16   50  4.77    5.9
03PC03-16   53  5.1 5.9
03PC03-16   60  5.57    7
03PC04-15   9   0.26    0.21
03PC04-15   15  0.64    0.77
03PC04-15   22  0.99    1.5
03PC04-15   29  1.83    2.6
03PC04-15   36  2.25    3.7
03PC04-15   43  3.23    4.8
03PC04-15   50  4.82    5.9
03PC04-15   53  5.2 5.9
03PC04-15   60  5.64    7
03PC05-15   11  0.42    0.21
03PC05-15   18  0.94    0.77
03PC05-15   25  0.83    1.5
03PC05-15   32  1.5 2.6
03PC05-15   39  2.28    3.7
03PC05-15   46  2.92    4.8
03PC05-15   49  3.3 5.9
03PC05-15   56  3.55    7
03PC06-16   11  0.42    0.21
03PC06-16   18  0.94    0.77
03PC06-16   25  0.84    1.5
03PC06-16   32  1.53    2.6
03PC06-16   39  2.69    3.7
03PC06-16   46  3.82    4.8
03PC06-16   49  4.3 5.9
03PC06-16   56  5.37    7
03PC07-15   12  0.42    0.21
03PC07-15   18  0.94    0.77
03PC07-15   25  0.99    1.5
03PC07-15   32  1.82    2.6
03PC07-15   39  2.65    3.7
03PC07-15   46  3.04    4.8
03PC07-15   53  3.45    5.9
03PC07-15   56  3.9 7
03PC07-15   63  4.77    8.1
03PC08-14   11  0.37    0.21
03PC08-14   17  0.84    0.77
03PC08-14   24  0.99    1.5
03PC08-14   31  1.75    2.6
03PC08-14   38  2.45    3.7
03PC08-14   45  3.07    4.8
03PC08-14   52  3.45    5.9
03PC08-14   55  3.95    5.9
03PC08-14   62  4.72    7
03PD01-14   7   0.19    0.21
03PD01-14   13  0.53    0.21
03PD01-14   20  1.14    0.77
03PD01-14   27  0.7 1.5
03PD01-14   34  1.75    2.6
03PD01-14   41  2.64    3.7
03PD01-14   48  3.49    4.8
03PD01-14   51  4.2 5.9
03PD01-14   58  5.2 7
03PD02-14   7   0.19    0.21
03PD02-14   13  0.53    0.21
03PD02-14   20  1.14    0.77
03PD02-14   27  0.85    1.5
03PD02-14   34  1.85    2.6
03PD02-14   41  2.85    3.7
03PD02-14   48  5.35    4.8
03PD02-14   51  5.5 5.9
03PD02-14   58  6.5 7
03PD03-14   11  0.37    0.21
03PD03-14   17  0.84    0.77
03PD03-14   24  0.78    1.5
03PD03-14   31  1.78    2.6
03PD03-14   38  2.55    3.7
03PD03-14   45  3.43    4.8
03PD03-14   52  5.2 5.9
03PD03-14   55  5.4 5.9
03PD03-14   62  6.2 7
03PD04-14   9   0.26    0.21
03PD04-14   15  0.64    0.77
03PD04-14   22  0.65    1.5
03PD04-14   29  1.84    2.6
03PD04-14   36  2.62    3.7
03PD04-14   43  3.38    4.8
03PD04-14   50  5.51    5.9
03PD04-14   53  5.85    5.9
03PD04-14   60  6.95    7
03PD05-15   7   0.19    0.21
03PD05-15   13  0.53    0.21
03PD05-15   20  1.14    0.77
03PD05-15   27  0.55    1.5
03PD05-15   34  1.53    2.6
03PD05-15   41  2.7 3.7
03PD05-15   48  3.57    4.8
03PD05-15   51  4.1 5.9
03PD05-15   58  5.1 7
03PD06-14   9   0.26    0.21
03PD06-14   15  0.64    0.77
03PD06-14   22  0.6 1.5
03PD06-14   29  1.7 2.6
03PD06-14   36  2.76    3.7
03PD06-14   43  3.37    4.8
03PD06-14   50  4.36    5.9
03PD06-14   53  4.7 5.9
03PD06-14   60  5.6 7
03PD07-15   7   0.22    0.21
03PD07-15   10  0.37    0.21
03PD07-15   17  0.84    0.77
03PD08-15   9   0.26    0.21
03PD08-15   15  0.64    0.77
03PD08-15   22  0.7 1.5
03PD08-15   29  1.85    2.6
03PD08-15   36  2.65    3.7
03PD08-15   43  3.4 4.8
03PD08-15   50  5.15    5.9
03PD08-15   53  5.6 5.9
03PD08-15   60  6.6 7
05PA05-13   11  0   0.21
05PA05-13   17  0   0.77
05PA05-13   24  0   1.5
05PA05-13   25  0   1.5
05PB01-14   9   0   0.21
05PB01-14   9   0   0.21
05PB01-14   22  1.4 1.5
05PB01-14   30  2.4 2.6
06PA01-13   10  0.37    0.21
06PA01-13   17  0.84    0.77
06PA01-13   24  1.1 1.5
06PA01-13   31  2.3 2.6
06PA01-13   34  3.23    2.6
06PA01-13   41  4.61    3.7
06PA02-14   10  0.37    0.21
06PA02-14   17  0.84    0.77
06PA02-14   24  1   1.5
06PA02-14   31  2.1 2.6
06PA02-14   34  3.23    2.6
06PA02-14   41  4.1 3.7
06PA03-14   12  0.48    0.21
06PA03-14   19  1.04    0.77
06PA03-14   26  0.75    1.5
06PA03-14   29  2   2.6
06PA03-14   36  2.52    3.7
06PA04-13   12  0.48    0.21
06PA04-13   19  1.04    0.77
06PA04-13   26  0.82    1.5
06PA04-13   29  2.08    2.6
06PA04-13   36  2.6 3.7
06PA05-14   11  0.42    0.21
06PA05-14   18  0.94    0.77
06PA05-14   25  0.73    1.5
06PA05-14   28  2.16    2.6
06PA05-14   35  2.4 3.7
06PA06-14   11  0.42    0.21
06PA06-14   18  0.94    0.77
06PA06-14   25  0.81    1.5
06PA06-14   28  2.16    2.6
06PA06-14   35  2.8 3.7
06PA07-14   13  0.53    0.21
06PA07-14   20  1.14    0.77
06PA07-14   27  0.89    1.5
06PA07-14   30  2.09    2.6
06PA07-14   37  2.75    3.7
06PA08-14   13  0.53    0.21
06PA08-14   20  1.14    0.77
06PA08-14   27  0.91    1.5
06PA08-14   30  2.11    2.6
06PA08-14   37  2.82    3.7
06PB01-13   10  0.37    0.21
06PB01-13   17  0.84    0.77
06PB01-13   24  1   1.5
06PB01-13   31  2.2 2.6
06PB01-13   34  3.23    2.6
06PB01-13   41  4.48    3.7
06PB02-13   10  0.37    0.21
06PB02-13   17  0.84    0.77
06PB02-13   24  0.6 1.5
06PB02-13   31  1.61    2.6
06PB02-13   34  3.23    2.6
06PB02-13   41  3.5 3.7
06PB03-13   11  0.42    0.21
06PB03-13   18  0.94    0.77
06PB03-13   25  0.85    1.5
06PB03-13   28  2.16    2.6
06PB03-13   35  3   3.7
06PB04-13   11  0.42    0.21
06PB04-13   18  0.94    0.77
06PB04-13   25  0.73    1.5
06PB04-13   28  2.16    2.6
06PB04-13   35  2.5 3.7
06PB05-13   11  0.42    0.21
06PB05-13   18  0.94    0.77
06PB05-13   25  0.85    1.5
06PB05-13   28  2.3 2.6
06PB05-13   35  3   3.7
06PB06-13   11  0.42    0.21
06PB06-13   18  0.94    0.77
06PB06-13   25  1   1.5
06PB06-13   28  2.16    2.6
06PB06-13   35  2.8 3.7
06PB07-13   13  0.53    0.21
06PB07-13   20  1.14    0.77
06PB07-13   27  0.75    1.5
06PB07-13   30  0.95    2.6
06PB07-13   37  2.5 3.7
06PB08-14   13  0.53    0.21
06PB08-14   20  1.14    0.77
06PB08-14   27  0.9 1.5
06PB08-14   30  1.2 2.6
06PB08-14   37  3.5 3.7
06PC07-13   7   0.22    0.21
06PC07-13   14  0.59    0.77
06PC07-13   21  1.24    1.5
06PC07-13   24  0.88    1.5
06PC07-13   31  2   2.6
06PC08-13   13  0.19    0.21
06PC08-13   20  0.19    0.77
06PC08-13   23  0.19    1.5
```

I want the data to be like these

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| 01PA05-18  | 01PA06-18  | 01PA07-18  | 01PA08-18  | 01PA09-18  | Target |
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+--------+
| DOC |  ABW | DOC |  ABW | DOC |  ABW | DOC |  ABW | DOC |  ABW |  ABW   |
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+--------+
|   6 |    0 |   5 |    0 |   5 |    0 |   5 |    0 |   5 |    0 |   0.2  |
|  13 | 0.53 |  12 | 0.48 |  12 | 0.48 |  12 | 0.48 |  12 | 0.48 |   0.77 |
|  20 | 1.14 |  19 | 1.04 |  19 | 1.04 |  19 | 1.04 |  19 | 1.04 |   1.5  |
|  27 | 0.92 |  26 | 0.74 |  26 | 0.72 |  26 | 0.7  |  26 | 0.71 |   2.6  |
|  34 | 1.49 |  33 | 1.25 |  33 | 1.32 |  33 | 1.30 |  33 | 1.22 |   3.7  |
|  41 | 1.91 |  40 | 1.82 |  40 | 1.84 |  40 | 1.80 |  40 | 1.85 |   4.8  |
|  48 | 2.64 |  47 | 3.12 |  47 | 3.05 |  47 | 3.07 |  47 | 2.90 |   5.9  |
|  55 | 3.69 |  54 | 4.40 |  54 | 4.12 |  54 | 3.72 |  54 | 3.74 |   7    |
|  62 | 4.19 |  61 | 5.44 |  61 | 5.21 |  61 | 4.52 |  61 | 4.40 |   8.1  |
|  65 | 4.72 |  64 | 6.46 |  64 | 6.00 |  64 | 5.11 |  64 | 4.92 |   9.2  |
|  72 | 5.74 |  71 | 7.30 |  71 | 6.90 |  71 | 5.87 |  71 | 5.78 |  10.3  |
+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+------+--------+
```

Comment: You can't have multiple row level column titles. You have to write column titles first and then data rows.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in a presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

try using case

```
Case when PondCrop =01PA03-18
then //your code
else //your code
end case as 01PA03-18
```